# Joomla 3: Serialize javascript object and save in session via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, session-variables, joomla3.0

I have a script on a Joomla page which must send an javascript object like this:

```
{ "44-00-22": "1" }
```

I want to send this via ajax to the controller and store it in the the session. Ajax call looks like this:

```
url='index.php?option=com_mycom&task=saveBasket&format=raw';    
        var data = "request=" + JSON.stringify(basket);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data ,
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                SqueezeBox.open("index.php?option=com_basket&view=basket&tmpl=component",{ 
                    handler : 'iframe',
                    size : {
                        x : 600,
                        y : 450
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The method in the controller:

```
public function saveBasket (){
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $request = $input->get('request', '');
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set('request', $request);

    echo "saved";   
}
```

After that I tried to access this in the com_basket basket view but it is a plain string like this and no json string that I could decode:

```
44-00-221
```

What is the correct way to accomplish that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its only the input type:

```
 $request = $input->get('request', '', 'raw');
```

it defaults to 'cmd' which filters the brackets. With type 'raw' everything works as expected.